# JSP - Passing values to modal on the same page

Tags: javascript, jsp, bootstrap-4, struts2, bootstrap-modal

I have a JSP page that contains a username and a button, When I click on the button I want to pass the username to the modal then in the click on the modal button I send the username to the back-end (struts2 action). (Scenario illustrated in the below picture)

I tried to pass username with onClick :

```
<%-- Page.jsp --%>
<button onclick="document.forms[0].username.value='BOB'; toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   <fmt:message key='Delete user'/>
</button>
<jsp:include page="deleteUserModal.jsp"/>
```

On the modal I want to read unsername value :

```
<%-- Modal.jsp --%>
<button onclick="document.forms[0].username.value='???';document.forms[0].action='deleteMethod';document.forms[0].submit();">
  <fmt:message key='delete'/>
</button>
```

Any idea please,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You trying to access elements from the another window. To customize the modal content you should use HTML `data-*`  attributes. See how to use [verying modal content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) with bootstrap.

```xml
<button onclick="document.forms[0].username.value='BOB'; toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-username='BOB'>
   <fmt:message key='Delete user'/>
</button>
```

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var username = button.data('username') 
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-body button').click(function(){
    alert(username);
})
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I fixed it by passing the scope :
<c:set var="username" value="BOB" scope="request"/>

Comment: Welcome, the check box is on the left of the answer.